# ctypes - structure contains garbage / not correct data

Tags: python, c++, 64-bit, ctypes

I have a C++ DLL (64bit) that takes as input a double pointer to a structure (i.e. a pointer to an array of structures). The function dynamically allocates the array of structures and 'then populates each structures elements (elements include: integers, floats, doubles, static arrays, another structure, and dynamically allocated arrays).

I've created a python class to mimic the structure (all data elements). However, when I call the C++ function - CreateROIs( .. ) - from python , I get garbage / wrong values for some of the elements in the structure.

Example, I'll get ppMem[0].spic=24609435234

Interestingly, if I pass that same data structure back to the C++ DLL and print out the elements in C++ they are still correct (function / code not provided for this part below).

I'm assuming it's an issue with data types (doubles / floats) when moving data between 64Bit python and C++ DLLs. Or maybe not having contiguous memory for the structure? I can't seem to track it down... Anyways, any help is much appreciated!

Here's my code and thanks for the help!

C++ DLL code:

```
// TriangleMesh struct where mesh is defined by vertices connected via triangles
// <summary>
extern "C"

struct MyDLL_API TriangleMesh
{
    int nbrVertices;
    int nbrTriangles;

    float* vertices;
    int* triangles;
};

extern "C"
struct MyDLL_API ROI 
{
    double xmm;
    double ymm;
    double zmm;
    double diameter;
    double level;
    double volume;
    double threshold;
    int isMesh;
    double mVol;
    double mass;
    double meanD;
    double dve;
    double dla;
    double dsa;
    double dla3D;
    double spike; 
    float sphere;

    float lais[6];  
    float sais[6];  
    float la3D[6];      

    TriangleMesh mesh;
};

extern "C" MyDLL_API
void CreateROIs(ROI** ppMem, int* NumROIs);

void CreateROIs(ROI** ppMem, int* NumROIs)
{
    *ppMem = (ROI *)malloc(sizeof(ROI) * (*NumROIs));

    for (int i = 0; i < *nbrNodules; i++)
    {
        (*ppMem)[i].xmm = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].ymm = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].zmm = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].diameter = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].level = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].volume= double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].threshold = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].mVol= double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].mass = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].meanD= double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].dve = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].dla = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].dsa = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].dla3D = double(i + 10.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].spike = double(i + 1.0);
        (*ppMem)[i].sphere = double(i + 1.0);

        int arr_size = sizeof((*ppMem)[i].longAxis3D) / sizeof((*ppMem)[i].longAxis3D[0]);

        for (int j = 0; j < arr_size; j++)
        {
            float val = arr_size * i + j;
            (*ppMem)[i].lais[j] = val;
            (*ppMem)[i].sais[j] = val;
            (*ppMem)[i].la3D[j] = val;
        }


        (*ppMem)[i].meshWasCreatedByDll = int(i+1);
        (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrVertices = int(rand() % 10 + 1);
        (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrTriangles = int(rand() % 10 + 1);

        (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.vertices = (float *)malloc(sizeof(float) * (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrVertices);
        (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.triangles = (int *)malloc(sizeof(int) * (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrTriangles);

        for (int j = 0; j < (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrVertices; j++)
        {
            (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.vertices[j] = float(j + 1);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.nbrTriangles; j++)
        {
            (*ppMem)[i].segMesh.triangles[j] = int(j + 1);
        }

    }
}
```

}

Python Code:

```
from ctypes import *
import numpy as np
from numpy.ctypeslib import ndpointer

ndDLL = cdll.LoadLibrary("./MyDll.dll")

# Triangle Mesh Structure
class TriangleMesh(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("nbrVertices", c_int),
        ("nbrTriangles", c_int),
        ("vertices", POINTER(c_float)),
        ("triangles",POINTER(c_int))]

# LCSNoduleEx Structure
class ROI(Structure):
    _fields_ = [
        ("xmm", c_double),
        ("ymm", c_double),
        ("zmm", c_double),
        ("diameter", c_double),
        ("level", c_double),
        ("volume", c_double),
        ("threshold", c_double),
        ("isMesh", c_int),
        ("mVol", c_double),
        ("mass", c_double),
        ("meanD", c_double),
        ("dve", c_double),
        ("dla", c_double),
        ("dsa", c_double),
        ("dla3D", c_double),
        ("spike", c_double), 
        ("sphere", c_float),

        ("lais", c_float*6),   
        ("said", c_float*6), 
        ("la3D", c_float*6),       

        ("mesh", TriangleMesh)
     ]


def PrintROI(pMem, NumROI):

    for i in range():):
        print("ROI %d"%(i), flush=True)
        print("\tlevel %f"%(pMem[i].level), flush=True)
        print("\tdiameter %f"%(pMem[i].diameter), flush=True)
        print("\tdla3D %f"%(pMem[i].dla3D), flush=True)
        print("\tddla %f"%(pMem[i].dla), flush=True)
        print("\tmeanD %f"%(pMem[i].meanD), flush=True)
        print("\tdai %f"%(pMem[i].dai), flush=True)
        print("\tdve %f"%(pMem[i].dve), flush=True)

        print("\tmass %f"%(pMem[i].mass), flush=True)

        print("\tthreshold %f"%(pMem[i].threshold), flush=True)

        print("\tspiculation %f"%(pMem[i].spike), flush=True)
        print("\tspiculation2 %f"%(pMem[i].sphere), flush=True)

        print("\tvolume %f"%(pMem[i].volume), flush=True)
        print("\tmVol %f"%(pMem[i].mVol), flush=True)
        print("\txmm %f"%(pMem[i].xmm), flush=True)
        print("\tymm %f"%(pMem[i].ymm), flush=True)
        print("\tzmm %f"%(pMem[i].zmm), flush=True)

        print("\tla3D %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f"%(pMem[i].la3D[0],
                                                    pMem[i].la3D[1],
                                                    pMem[i].la3D[2],
                                                    pMem[i].la3D[3],
                                                    pMem[i].la3D[4],
                                                    pMem[i].la3D[5]), flush=True)

        print("\tsais %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f"%(pMem[i].sais[0],
                                                           pMem[i].sais[1],
                                                           pMem[i].sais[2],
                                                           pMem[i].sais[3],
                                                           pMem[i].sais[4],
                                                           pMem[i].sais[5]), flush=True)

        print("\tLAIS %f, %f, %f, %f, %f, %f"%(pMem[i].lais[0],
                                                            pMem[i].lais[1],
                                                            pMem[i].lais[2],
                                                            pMem[i].lais[3],
                                                            pMem[i].lais[4],
                                                            pMem[i].lais[5]), flush=True)

        print("\tisMesh %d"%(pMem[i].isMesh), flush=True)


        print("\tnbrVertices %d"%(pMem[i].mesh.nbrVertices))
        print("\tnbrTriangles %d"%(pMem[i].mesh.nbrTriangles))


        for j in range(pMem[i].mesh.nbrVertices):
            print("\t\tVertices %d) %f"%(j,pMem[i].mesh.vertices[j]), flush=True)

        for j in range(pMem[i].mesh.nbrTriangles):
            print("\t\tTriangle %d) %d"%(j,pMem[i].mesh.triangles[j]), flush=True)

ndDLL.CreateROI.argtypes  = [POINTER(POINTER(ROI)), POINTER(c_int)]

pMem= POINTER(LCSNoduleEx)()
NumROI = c_int(1)

ndDLL.CreateROI(byref(pMem),byref(NumROI) )


PrintROI(pMem, NumROI.value)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your two structures have at least two mismatches.

I don't know which, if either, is relevant, because your garbage seems to be in a field named `spic`, which doesn't appear in either the C++ struct or the ctypes one…

---

First, you get two fields out of order:

```
double threshold;
int isMesh;
double mVol;
```

vs.

```
("threshold", c_double),
("mVol", c_double),
("isMesh", c_int),
```

This might seem like no big deal, but once you put alignment-driven padding into the mix, it's conceivable that this could cause all of the subsequent fields to be 4 bytes off.

---

And then, you use the wrong types for all of these arrays:

```
float lais[6];  
float sais[6];  
float la3D[6];
```

vs.

```
("lais", c_double*6),   
("said", c_double*6), 
("la3D", c_double*6),
```

A `float` is 32 bits; a `c_double` is 64 bits. `lais[0]` is a garbage double consisting of `lais[0]` and `lais[1]` packed together as a double, `lais[4]` is `sais[2]` and `sais[3]` packaged together, `la3D[4]` is 64 random bits out of the heap past the end of the structure. If you're lucky, you get a segfault when you try to read that, but if not, you get hard-to-debug garbage.

---

For really complicated structs like this, I usually don't trust myself to write the ctypes version manually without making at least three times as many mistakes as you did. Instead, I write a quick script to parse the header (or, occasionally, the docs) and generate the Python code. For things like CoreFoundation and Win32 headers, that have thousands of ridiculously huge structs all written in a very rigid and reliable style, I have scripts that I use over and over again.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. It was actually my bad to post the code mid-changes. Infact I have ordered the variables similarily and also ensured that types match: for example ("lais", float*6 ). Still the same problem ...

Comment: Ah found the issue thanks to your suggestion @abarnert, turns out I declared the same variable twice in the python structure. I've fixed the code in the above question so now it should work. Thanks again for the recommendations.

Comment: @ShawnS I did exactly the same thing with a WIn32 API struct, and spent a whole weekend hunting down pretty much the same bug you're seeing, and it was so annoying that I still vividly remember it a decade later, which is exactly why I always write a script to generate the code. :)